# flask migrate - not detecting addition of new column

Tags: python, flask, alembic

Having a tough time getting Flask-migrate to detect new column in a table. My guess is that something isn't getting imported, or I'm importing things in the incorrect order.

The app is instantiated by a `__init__.py` file. The overall directory of the app is structured as such:

```
|-static/
|-templates/
|__init__.py
|filters.py
|models.py
|forms.py
|utils.py
|views.py
```

The relevant part of the `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
# Import flask and template operators
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint
import os
# Import SQLAlchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads
from flask_mail import Mail
# Define the WSGI application object
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configurations
app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join('..','config.py'))

# Define the database object which is imported
# by modules and controllers
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from . import models
migrate = Migrate(app, db,compare_type=True)

mail = Mail(app)
```

In the command line I set `export FLASK_APP=<app_name>`

I make the change to the `models.py` file, adding a new column to one of my tables.

Then I run the command `flask db migrate`

However the only output I get from the above command is:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
```

And there is no new migration script added to the `versions` directory of the `migrations` folder. This has worked in the past and I'm not sure why it's no longer working.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who may be struggling with this problem, a couple things I did to help:

1) upgrade to the latest version of flask-migrate. this fixed (most) of the issues for me.

2) if you have old migrations, move them to a new folder (eg `mv migrations/ migrations_old`) and then re-init migrations with `flask db init`. Then make the changes you want to the database, and check that the new migration script was correctly created.

Of course, no guarantees that this will work though. I still never figured out the root issue for my case but these two steps worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when there is an existing migration that I had not deployed yet. After running `flask db upgrade`, then flask-migrate was able to detect the new column.